# how to add LineBreak in Whatsapp message using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, whatsapp

This is my URL: `https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=0000000000000&text=LineBreak`

I need to put a line break in the middle of the `text` param value. I've tried `<br>`, `%0a`, and white space `" "`, but nothing works. Could someone please help me?

Comment: What you use depends on how you use it. A URL can't have a line break. Only the code that accepts the parameter string can use a line break. Please revise to tell us more about that.

Comment: Have you tried `\n`? Or `%5Cn`?

Comment: I have a <a> tag with this url, and when the user click on the link, a new window open and the message need to appear with a line break for the user, but i don't know how pass the line break like a parameter

Comment: \n doesn't work and %5Cn when the user start the chat appear like \n and not a line break

Comment: Try `%0A`, as in `&text=Line%0ABreak`

Comment: i try now Line%0ABreak but  just result in Line Break and don't a line break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that you can add a linebreak in whatsApp API Using

```js
encodeURI('\n')
```